# Not able to get values in console.log in Angular 8

Tags: angular

I am trying to get every skill value, so that i can put it in my const body for api calling,

```
const firstEmployeeSkills = this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills.map(x => x.skill).value;
return firstEmployeeSkills;
```

i have written this in the body but it still does not show in console....i want the skill value to be displayed in the console

here's my demo with errors for that
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx

this is the body i need to pass

```
submit(){
    const body = {
        firstName: Rakshanda,
        lastName: Bhure,
        skills: [
            {
                skill: java,
                exp: python,
            },

            {
                skill: php,
                exp: angular,
            }
            ..
        ]
    }
}
```

so i put this...to get values, but not able to get skill and exp values

```
submit() {
    const body = {
        firstName: this.employeeFirstName(empIndex).value,
        lastName: this.employeeLastName(empIndex).value,
        skills: [
            {
                skill: this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills.map(x => x.skill),
                exp: this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills.map(x => x.exp),
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give the steps to reproduce and error information

Comment: do you want all skill list?

Comment: yes skill list...I put .vale at the end  of it, but it isnt working

Comment: const firstEmployeeSkills = this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills.map(x => x.skill)

Comment: No need to put value, just remove it and check

Comment: you can check the edit, that what i am trying to pass as body

Comment: so you want above object?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a29jfx after removing value, it gives an array and it gives "Object" written instead of value

Comment: I am not able to understand your requirements, can you please explain with what is expected

Comment: @ If you want the value that you have shared in the question then just use `console.log(this.empForm.value)`

Comment: please check the updated question, I just need skills value, suppose I enter skill as 1, then it should display "1" in the console, as I have to manipulate this value in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the skills of first employee with below peace of code:

```
onSubmit() {
  let body = {
    firstName: this.empForm.value.employees[0].firstName,
    lastName: this.empForm.value.employees[0].lastName,
    skills: this.empForm.value.employees[0].skills
  }
  console.log(body);
  return body;    
}
```

Now you can use the local variable **body** for the API calls.

[image: Result in console]

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hey, that works thanks, but, suppose i put 1 as my skill and submit, then in console it says ["1"], instead I just want to appear as ''1''...can you please tell me how to do it

Comment: The skills will be an array. So better option is get the employees skills array (with experience and skill) and then add the info to your skills array (Array of object with properties skill and exp).

Comment: I need to get just the skills value with out the array brackets, cuz i need to manipuate it in the body, suppose i enter skill value as 1, I am getting["1"], instead i just need "1", as i need to manipulate it in the body

Comment: With this code, you will get - body:
{"firstName":"Anoop","lastName":"Warrier","skills":[{"skill":"Anagular","exp":"1"},{"skill":"Java","exp":"2"}]}

Comment: mapping gives array, i need it in this format -->  scheduleTiming(schedule_index: number): FormArray {
    return this.schedule_list()
      .at(schedule_index)
      .get("schedule_slot_list") as FormArray;
  }   -- this code is giving me skill and exp values in an array, i need to just get skill val